# Calculate angle between two rectangle in perspective projection

Tags: camera-calibration, perspective

[Image of retangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5SFf.jpg)

I know how to find the vanishing point from the four corner and calculate the camera intrinsic matrix. But i don't know how to use this information to find the angle between the rectangle.

Comment: Size of white paper known to us?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1. Paper size is known in meters

Consider one corner of paper as origin and with corresponding image and world coordinates obtain Rotation and translation using SolvePnP() utility of Opencv. Now that you have rotation of paper in Camera space, you can do projective transform of image using intrinsics and Rotation information (also called as Orthorectification). Now you obtain rectified image as if it's capture by keeping camera up above pointing it perfectly downwards.

Case 2. Paper size is not known

As vanishing points are known, there's a standard method to obtain orientation of camera from vanishing points and vanishing line(line connecting two vanishing points). Apply perspective transform to get rectified image where you can measure angle directly